# Limit law by using precise definition of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Can you show me the way how to prove the limit law by using the precise definition of limits. This is the limit law:

> If $f(x) \leq g(x)$ when $x$ is near $a$ and the limits of $f$ and $g$ both exists as $x$ approaches $a$, then $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) \leq \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$$

Comment: If you define the limit to only be taken inside the domain then its immediate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume by absurd that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)>\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$. Get $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)>c>\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$, by definition of limit, exist $\delta>0$ Satisfying for all $x,\, |x-a|<\delta$ $$f(x)>c>g(x).$$
Contradiction

Comment: Can you explain more clearly for me? Why don't we prove it directly

Comment: Yes we can!, change the phrase “assume by absurd” for “By tricotomy, either $\le$ or $>$ occurs, we gonna proof that the case $>$ not occurs”. One question : if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $a\le\epsilon+b$, then (we can directly proof that) $a\le b$?. The point is : Is confortable work with limit when we have an “air-gap” to this, cause the definition of limits create “sensible spaces” around the limit value, when we assume the strictly inequality this “space” appear around the limit values.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $\delta>0$ as the minimum of the corresponding $\delta$'s for $f$ and $g$ and *choose* $x_0$ with $0<|x_0-a|<\delta$. Then $$\begin{align} \lim_{x\to a}f(x) &= \lim_{x\to a}f(x) -f(x_0)+f(x_0) \\ &< \epsilon + g(x_0) \\ &=\epsilon + g(x_0)-\lim_{x\to a}g(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x) \\ &< 2\epsilon +\lim_{x\to a}g(x). \end{align}$$If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)<2\epsilon +\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$. If you don't like the factor $2$, you could pick the $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon/2$ instead of $\epsilon$.

Comment: can you explain why limf(x)< 2ϵ +limg(x) then limf(x)<=limg(x)